Power Apps form not showing the selected date from SharePoint calendar when adding new item
Scenario - use SharePoint list calendar view to add event by integrating power apps form.
This is the default add new item in SharePoint list calendar view. It picks up the time block I highlighted in the calendar.
However, when I integrate Power Apps by customizing the form, when I highlight a time block from a different day in the calendar, it doesn't reflect in the Power Apps form.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Is there any way to set the DefaultDate property of the date picker in PowerApps to reflect the date and time selected in the SharePoint Calendar View?
Appreciate your help!
